# Can the new dragon types of Wyrmblessed be used for other character options?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

[Wyrmblessed Bloodline](https://2e.aonprd.com/Bloodlines.aspx?ID=17) introduced *primal* and *imperial* dragons, with new damage types like piercing and negative.

Can they be used for example in the Kobold Breath ancestry feat or Dragon Instinct of Barbarians?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes (for PFS)

As SpearCarrier.no2's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/209340/) mentions, PFS has issued campaign clarification allowing players to select these options for characters with similar draconic connections to the wyrmblessed bloodline.

While it does not call out Kobolds specifically though, I do think they would count just as the draconic bloodline, or draconic instinct would.

### Outside PFS, no.

The [Kobold Ancestry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Ancestries.aspx?ID=18) states:

> Choose a type of chromatic or metallic dragon to be your exemplar.

Primal and Imperial dragons are not chromatic or metallic.

Barbarian's [Dragon Instinct](https://2e.aonprd.com/Instincts.aspx?ID=2) states:

> Select a type of dragon from Table 3–4: Dragon Instincts to be your instinct's dragon type.

Primal and Imperial Dragons are not listed on that table, nor are there any rules for adding such to the list of available instincts.

With PFS's note though, it'd be simple to houserule it working the same way.

Comment: While Primal and Imperial dragons are not chromatic or metallic, Wyrmblessed also offers you to select chromatic or metallic dragons which work both for Kobold Ancestry and Dragon Instinct. So  the Wyrmblessed Bloodline works with these options as long as you select them. So while you are correctly showcasing why the two types of dragons don't work you incorretly state a blanked "No." when they clearly can be used for other character options - as long as they meet the requirements (such as correct selection of dragon). You can select primal and imperial, but you don't have to.

Comment: @Akixkisu The question is "Can the **new** dragon types ..." Chromatic and metallic dragons aren't new, therefore they're not relevant to the question and the answer is a blanket "No." since we're discussing only primal and imperial dragons.

Comment: The question is: Can one use them for other character options? - In the title. Yes, one can. The second question: "Can they be used for example[...?]" Whether "they" refers to Wyrmblessed, primal and imperial dragons, or damage types like piercing and negative the querent leaves open (at 4/5 close votes, we should close it) or whether this is the conditional that makes explicit that the querent looks for other than these character options that they are aware of that one can't use them for - "for example[:...] Kobold Breath ancestry feat or Dragon Instinct of Barbarians[.]"

Comment: Admittedly, neither of us should have answered the question until the querent clarified their question.

Comment: Sure, if you ignore the obvious context of the question, I'm wrong, but then you have a new question. Their question is clear enough for me, which is why I haven't voted to close it. It exited the review queue with plenty of votes to leave it open, which means others agree with me.

Comment: Considering their other questions, it is unclear whether the querent wants to switch the character build because they have realised that it doesn't work out or whether they seek options to combine them with, especially since they consider the Adopted Ancestry feat.

Comment: However, they accepted your answer, so it is probably in their best interest if you adjust the question to fit your answer for it to remain open.

Comment: Notably, this would probably be fairly easy homebrew territory for a GM, and I don't see or know of anything that would make it unbalanced.

Comment: It is PFS I am participating in, so homebrew is not good enough. I was hoping for a sentence in the book that didn't get to the online part, about "the new options can be used instead of metallic or chromatic dragons for any character option". Like composite bows for example.

Answer (score 4):

## Yes (at least in Pathfinder Society play)

There is a PFS note in the [Dragon Instinct](https://2e.aonprd.com/Instincts.aspx?ID=2) now:

> The wyrmblessed sorcerer bloodline provides options for primal and imperial dragons. Character with a similar draconic connection, such as draconic bloodline sorcerors or **draconic instinct barbarians**, can also select from these dragon types. You must own a copy of Lost Omens: The Mwangi Expanse to select these options.

PFS notes usually (but not always) find their way into the errata, so I would allow it outside of Society play too.